# Switch Statement Default Case Fall Through

Tags: java, scjp

Here is a small confusion so kindly pardon my ignorance. Here is a code snippet.

```
public class SwitchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 2;

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("helllo");
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Benjamin");
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Here, if value of x is 2, only `Benjamin` is printed. That's perfectly fine. Now lets suppose, i change value of `x to 3`, not matching any case, than `its a fall through from default case`. Ain't compiler needs to match every case for 3, by that time `CASE 2` will be passed, than why it goes back to default and prints hello Benjamin. Can someone explain please?

Thanks,

Comment: Notice how you can put the `case 2` before the `case 1`. There's no value order to cases. They are "visited" in order of appearance.

Comment: If you don't add break at the end of your case, as you did on default, it will execute the next cases until a break command.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thats not a my question, my question is why there is a fall through if x is not matching any case. Obviously compiler would move top to down to match every case, but when its 3, it seems to go back and fall through from default. I know its simple, but trying to understand the logic.

Comment: It's not going backwards. It matches `default` and falls through to `case 2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `break;` statement to break out of the `switch` block.

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("helllo");
        break; // <-- add this here
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Benjamin");
        break;

    }
```

Generally speaking, it is also better coding practice to have your `default:` case be the last case in the `switch` block.

In this case, the switch is following the pattern:

```
x==1? No, check next case
default? Not done yet, check other cases
x==2? No, check next case
//No more cases, so go back to default
default? Yes, do default logic
// no break statement in default, so it falls through to case 2: logic without checking the case
output case 2 logic
break
```

Notice how the block will jump over the default case, and save it until a later time unless we have exhausted all other possible cases.

Comment: mike, my question is not that. My question is if the value of x is 2, it only prints Benjamin. If x value i change to 3, its a fall through case why. Won't it match cases for 3, one by one top down approach.

Comment: @benz I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking. What is the behavior that you are expecting to see? If `x==3`, it will enter the switch statement and say: `3==1?` which is false, so it skips that. `3==2?`, which is false so it skips that. Then since there are no other cases to check against, it defaults to the `default` case, which will catch anything. So it enters there and prints "Hello". Since you do not have a break in the default case, the `switch` block is never left, and it continues to go down the code until it either completes, or finds a `break`

Comment: @benz I see what you mean, you mean to say does it progress through a switch block top-down style. As in it will check: case 1, case default, then case 2? This is not the case, Switch blocks ALWAYS go into the default case should no other case be found to be correct.

Comment: i was thinking default will be checked after Case-1 as its appearing in middle. default is the last case checked by compiler. I got the point. Thank you so much.

Comment: that was exactly my confusion. Thank you so much. You saved the day :)

Comment: @benz Glad to have helped :). I've updated my answer with a brief summary of what we talked about in the comments for any future reference.

Answer (score 2):

It prints both strings because you do not have a `break` in your `default` case, so it continues into `case 2`, printing Benjamin. You could fix this by adding a `break` or moving `case 2` above the `default` case.

Answer (score 1):

'switch' case is other form of 'if-then-else', the default case is for the final else part. It is advisable to write default at the end of switch.

Answer (score 1):

Default is checked as last. Thats why it feels like the compiler 'went' back.